# Check Box check and Uncheck using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I am not able to list out the check boxes which are checked and unchecked.the checkboxes are placed in the div tags. And only class name is generated dynamically when the check box is clicked.

**Unchecked checkboxes:**

```
<div class="jqx-checkbox-default jqx-checkbox-default-p_p_id=TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_artifactTypeLabel=0&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_jspPage=%2Fhtml%2Fteam%2Fassign_user.jsp&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_token=ORGANIZATION&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_screenMode=maximized&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_artifactId=0&_TeamManage...l-p_p_id=TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_artifactTypeLabel=0&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_jspPage=%2Fhtml%2Fteam%2Fassign_user.jsp&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_token=ORGANIZATION&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_screenMode=maximized&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_artifactId=0&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_teamId=0">
<div style="width: 13px; height: 13px;">
<span class="" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;"></span>
</div>
```

**Checked checkboxes:**

```
<div class="jqx-checkbox-default jqx-checkbox-default-p_p_id=TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_artifactTypeLabel=0&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_jspPage=%2Fhtml%2Fteam%2Fassign_user.jsp&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_token=ORGANIZATION&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_screenMode=maximized&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_artifactId=0&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_teamId=0 jqx-fill-state-normal jqx-fill-state-normal-p_p_id=TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_artifactTypeLabel=0&_TeamManageme`nt_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_jspPage=%2Fhtml%2Fteam%2Fassign_user.jsp&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_token=ORGANIZATION&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_screenMode=maximized&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_artifactId=0&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_teamId=0 jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-p_p_id=TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_artifactTypeLabel=0&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_jspPage=%2Fhtml%2Fteam%2Fassign_user.jsp&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_token=ORGANIZATION&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_screenMode=maximized&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_artifactId=0&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_teamId=0">
<div style="width: 13px; height: 13px;">
<span class="jqx-checkbox-check-checked jqx-checkbox-check-checked-p_p_id=TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_artifactTypeLabel=0&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_jspPage=%2Fhtml%2Fteam%2Fassign_user.jsp&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_token=ORGANIZATION&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_screenMode=maximized&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_artifactId=0&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_teamId=0" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;"></span>
</div>
```

**The code:**

```
//Checked element is present in this div
WebElement weChecked=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div")); 
//Unchecked element is present in this div
WebElement weUnchecked=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div"));

//This the following code where I am checking
WebElement weUnchecked=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div"));
if(weUnchecked.isSelected())
{
    System.out.println("Selected");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Not Selected");
}
//WebElement weChecked=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div"));
WebElement weChecked=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div"));
if(weChecked.isSelected())
{
    System.out.println("Selected");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Not Selected");
}
```

Comment: There are no input elements in the code. Are you trying to list <span> elements with the jqx-checkbox class?

Comment: Ya there are no input elements just div and span they mentioned

Comment: Dynamically adding the grid check boxes as the data comes from database

Comment: Then can you post the HTML with a dynamically added check box?

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way is using CSS selector instead of xpath in this case.

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input:checked[type='checkbox']"))
```

should return the list with all selected checkboxes.

And this one for not selected:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input:not(:checked)[type='checkbox']"))
```

Comment: cssSelector is not mentioned only class is given in div and that too runtime

Comment: cssSelector is a way to find elements. Could you paste example of html code in comment? Example of selected and unselected checkbox

Comment: Please provide both selected and unselected html code. Please paste it in comment, not edit my answer

Comment: <div class="jqx-checkbox-default jqx-checkbox-default-p_p_id=TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_artifactTypeLabel=0&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_jspPage=%2Fhtml%2Fteam%2Fassign_user.jsp&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_token=ORGANIZATION&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_screenMode=maximized&_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_artifactId=0&_TeamManage...l-p_p_id=TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet&p_p_

Comment: In comments its accepting 250 char only.The div has more than 400 char

Comment: So edit your question. Remember to use formatting

Comment: Edited the question.Thank you I am new to this stackflow

Comment: Try this for unchecked: `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'jqx-checkbox-default')]/span[@class='']"))` and this for checked: `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'jqx-checkbox-default')]/span[contains(@class,'jqx-checkbox-check-checked']"))`. This commands should return lists of checked and unchecked spans.

Answer (score 0):

The `isSelected` works with attributes of HTML. The xpath or other else way is much better to use. Here is [Selenium Doc](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isSelected--).

**Here is html:**

```
<input id="foo" type="checkbox">
```

**Here is code:**

```
var foo = element(by.id('foo'));
expect(foo.isSelected()).toBe(false);
foo.click();
expect(foo.isSelected()).toBe(true);
```